# рекурсивная перезапись многомерного массива

Tags: php

есть два массива, многомерный и одномерный, я хочу их сравнить и добавить в многомерный массив новое значение. моя идея такая:

```
public function OptionTypeCategory($data, $TypeCategorys){
        foreach($data as $k => $item){
            if(isset($item['childs'])){
                $this->OptionTypeCategory($item['childs'], $TypeCategorys);
            } else {
                foreach($TypeCategorys as $tc) {
                   if($item['id'] == $tc['category_id']) {
                       $item['sel'] = 'select';
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

где $TypeCategorys простой одномерный массив
$item['sel'] = 'select'; - добавление в многомерный массив нового элемента.
но никаких добавлений нет! я уже не знаю что делать

по многочисленным просьбам читателей журнала "Незнайка" добавляем массивы.
Массив категорий из которых формируется список select ( в коде $data):

```
Array
(
[20] => Array
    (
        [id] => 20
        [parent_id] => 0
        [title] => Предоставление услуг
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [21] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 21
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Компьютерные услуги
                    )

                [28] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 28
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Риэлторские услуги
                    )

                [45] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 45
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Бизнес и консалтинг
                    )

                [47] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 47
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Здоровье и красота
                    )

                [48] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 48
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Помощь и консультирование
                    )

                [49] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 49
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Помощь по дому, химчистка
                    )

                [50] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 50
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Переводы
                    )

                [51] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 51
                        [parent_id] => 20
                        [title] => Реклама и дизайн
                    )

            )

    )

[22] => Array
    (
        [id] => 22
        [parent_id] => 0
        [title] => Недвижимость
        [childs] => Array
            (
                [23] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 23
                        [parent_id] => 22
                        [title] => Квартиры
                    )

                [24] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 24
                        [parent_id] => 22
                        [title] => Дома
                    )

                [25] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 25
                        [parent_id] => 22
                        [title] => Гаражи
                    )

                [26] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 26
                        [parent_id] => 22
                        [title] => Земельные учатски
                    )

            )

    )
)
```

массив типов которые относятся к категориям (в программе $TypeCategorys):

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 23
        [category_title] => Квартиры
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 24
        [category_title] => Дома
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [category_id] => 25
        [category_title] => Гаражи
    )

)
```

Comment: пардон, позволю себе еще вопрос: как Вы проверяете, что никаких добавлений нет?

Comment: давайте на javascript-e здесь напишем такую же функцию, если у Вас есть пример входных данных

Comment: после функции echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            echo '</pre>'

Comment: мне нужно именно на php, идея вообще такая, многомерный массив это многоуровневые категории в списке select (multiply) ($data) а в одномерном массиве $TypeCategorys типы которые относятся к каким-то категориям. так вот хочу сделать чтоб в списке категорий select были выделены все option где ид категории = ид опции

Comment: Вам сейчас надо понять, почему Ваш подход не работает, а язык значения не имеет. javascript можно написать и выполнить прямо здесь.

Comment: массивы в студию.

Comment: я поставил амперсант но новый элемент не $item['sel'] добавляется, т.е. при условии когда $item['id'] == $tc['category_id'] в массив должен добавиться новый элемент $item['sel'] равный 'select', но этого не происходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

наконец, вопрос решен и этот вопрос с облегчением можно закрыть.
А решение оказалось простым!!
спасибо уважаемому @PHPLego толчек! 
решение:

```
public function OptionTypeCategory(&$data, $TypeCategorys){
        foreach($data as $k => &$item){
            if(isset($item['childs'])){
                $this->OptionTypeCategory($item['childs'], $TypeCategorys);
            } else {
                foreach($TypeCategorys as $tc) {
                   if($item['id'] == $tc['category_id']) {
                       $item['sel'] = 'select';
                   }
                }
            }
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

как видно из кода **амперсанд** нужен был не только в цикле перед $item но так же и в функции перед $data.
спасибо всем читателям

Comment: Ох, действительно, просмотрел. Круто что все у вас заработало в итоге :)

Answer (score 2):

Ваша логика верна, вам всего лишь нужно добавить амперсанд перед $item в цикле foreach. Иначе это **копия** элемента, а не сам элемент и модификация его бесполезна.

```
public function OptionTypeCategory($data, $TypeCategorys){
    foreach($data as $k => &$item){
        if(isset($item['childs'])){
            $this->OptionTypeCategory($item['childs'], $TypeCategorys);
        } else {
            foreach($TypeCategorys as $tc) {
               if($item['id'] == $tc['category_id']) {
                   $item['sel'] = 'select';
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: я поставил амперсант но новый элемент не $item['sel'] добавляется, т.е. при условии когда $item['id'] == $tc['category_id'] в массив должен добавиться новый элемент $item['sel'] равный 'select', но этого не происходит